# Typeorm iterating over results fetched in chunks

Tags: typeorm

I want to iterate over some `respository.find` or `repository.createQueryBuilder` results. However the results including db field of type json or Buffer and thus can be big. Therefore I dont want to fetch all the results all at once to limit memory usage and instead proceed in chunks and wonder how to best do that with typeorm

I know that several frameworks/libraries (e.g. Stripe or Shopware) offer iterators for such purpose to proceed e.g. with syntax like

```
for await (const order of this.orders.list({ limit: 50 })) {
```

so chunks in 50 items would be fetched and processed which is really nice from a programming perspective.

Is there sth similar in typeorm?

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in feature. But I use the following code:

```
  async * iterate(options?: FindManyOptions<T>, limit = 100) {
    let skip = 0;
    for (; ;) {
      const items = await this.find({ ...options, skip, take: limit });
      yield* items;
      if (items.length === 0 || items.length < limit) {
        return;
      }
      skip += items.length;
    }
  }
```

**Important note**

Paginating using skip and limit isn't an ideal solution because performance gets worse as you fetch later pages.

You can implement a solution and use your entity fields.

For example:

```
where entity.index > :lastBatchLastEntityIndex
```